# Django search with postgres.search works incorrect and case-sensitive with Cyrillic letters

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to create search for my project with `postgres.search`. And it works but works incorrect. It works too precisely. For example: When I'm searching `bolu`, nothing is found. But when I'm searching `bolum` it founds. How can I fix it?

```
# filters.py

class DepartmentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    branch = filters.CharFilter(field_name="branches__id", lookup_expr="in")
    q = filters.CharFilter(method="search_filter")

    def search_filter(self, queryset, _, value):
        search_vector = SearchVector("name")
        search_query = SearchQuery(value)
        return (
            queryset.annotate(search=search_vector)
            .filter(search=search_query)
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ["branch", "q"]


# models.py

class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Branches"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    branches = models.ManyToManyField(Branch, related_name="department")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[[image: Not Works]

[image: Works]

Comment: This likely means that the collation of the database is wrong. Django does not work with that.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to filter departments by their name so you can write params in your filter method like this

```py
.filter(name__icontains=search_query)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no need to define a whole method to search by name. Try to define field `q` as

```
q = filters.CharFilter(field_name="name", lookup_expr="icontains")
```

This will fix both incorrect search and case-sensitivity with cyrillic letters